# Using the Django ORM, How can you create a unique hash for all possible combinations

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to maintain a Django model with a unique id for every combination of choices within the model. I would then like to be able to update the model with a new field and not have the previous unique id's change. 
The id's can be a hash or integer or anything.
What's the best way to achieve this?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    WINDOW_MIN = 5
    WINDOW_MAX = 7
    WINDOW_CHOICES = [(i,i) for i in range(WINDOW_MIN - 1, WINDOW_MAX - 1)]
    window = models.PositiveIntegerField('Window', editable=True, default=WINDOW_MIN, choices=WINDOW_CHOICES)
    is_live = models.BooleanField('Live', editable=True, default=False)
    unique_id = ....
```

Given the above example there will be 3 * 2 == 6 unique id's. If I add another editable boolean field, I don't want to change the previous unique id's but I want the new unique id's to be generated for the new boolean field.

The thought process behind this is the parameters in MyModel define the inputs to a function who's results are stored in another Django model `MyResultModel` by unique_id and the name of the model. The reasoning behind this is there are multiple variants of `MyModel` each with it's own set unique combination's that get updated regularly but the result set in MyResultModel is the same across MyModel1 to MyModelN. Ideally I would like the unique_id's to be autogenerated. In other words the key for the result set stored in `MyResultModel` is the model_name (MyModel) and a unique_id. I want to sanely manage this many (MyModel1,...MyModelN) to one (MyResultModel) relationship.

```
class MyResultModel(models.Model):
    unique_id = ...
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=False) # Points to a Django Model ex MyModel
    result1 = ...
    result2 = ...
```

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: @Chris I'll add more info on why I thought the above made sense.

Comment: I agree with @Chris comment, still, I'll try to answer.

Comment: @Chris I added a lot, let me know if that makes sense or if I'm thinking about this in a completely wrong way.

Comment: You could save yourself a lot of trouble with all this if you just used normal auto-incrementing keys on `MyModelN` and indexed each parameter/input field. You'd make 2 database calls instead of 1 but that's really not a big deal. Are you sure you need to make that optimisation?

Comment: @AlexHall I'm not sure the auto-incrementing keys would work could you provide a simple example using that?

Comment: What I mean is that you would do something like this: `MyResultModel.objects.get(model_name='MyModel', unique_id=MyModel.objects.get(window=6, is_live=True).id)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible solution is to store the parameters `JsonField`

https://bitbucket.org/schinckel/django-jsonfield

Answer (score 4):

A common approach, given that all your options are boolean, categorical or small numbers, you could just pack them into a bigger bit field (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) and whenever you add a new option, make sure to push it to the most-significant part of your bit field and avoid having a value of 0 (that is, simple add 1 to whatever). Not only would every single unique_id represent a different configuration, you could even do without the model and just use bit operations to extract all your values from the bit field.

Comment: There's a https://github.com/disqus/django-bitfield now I just need to look into how I can auto generate them, without losing the old ones when I add a new field.

Comment: I am not familiar with that, but from the docs, from a quick look, looks like it works with boolean flags only. It's the same idea, you can save a full "model" using this approach but you will need to tweak it to be able to store numbers.

Comment: Yeah true, it looks like I may be able to use this package actually https://github.com/goodmase/django-bitfield-manager

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 thing:
First, if you just want to create unique hash for all the combinations

```
# Just set it all together like
uniq= cb1+cb2+cb3... (a string key is ok =) )
# If it is very very long string ~> we think about using hash to short it (and have same size for all value).
```

And next:

For your question above:

i can't understand why do you make the model into a complicate thing (like a mess) but still have to solve it:

As i read your ques: you have many variants of Models ~> want to gather it into 1 model res?

So:
it is better to set FK

```
map = models.ForeignKey(Model_name, null=True)
# but if you have too many model, it can't be help...
```

So i recomment:

~ create just 1 model, because if you have too many model, you can't even call it to get data (As you did) but when you add more FIELD, unique id ~> should change.

One good way to have special unique_id:

## Use the first solution i said.

Or:

Create **NEW** table just to store YOUR COMBO:

New table will have ALL field and you will SET value for each (or you can write script to create it). ~> You have id for each combo ~> ***it same as unique id***

You can create ALL THE POSSIBLE combo or just check and add when the NEW combo show up

Comment: 1 thing to be care full (when add new field, you have to set default value or set it NULL-able)